# Customize Employee Form in OpenERP 7.0

Tags: inheritance, customization, field, odoo

I want to add a field "Employee File Number" to employee form in OpenERP 7.0. I have reviewed the official documentation, search on google but could not find a simple example. I am new to OpenERP if someone can provide a step by step example that would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/03_module_dev_05/ please read this,will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in your module.

**Py file:**

```
class hr_employee(osv.osv):

    _inhetit= 'hr.employee'

    _columns = {
        'emp_file':fields.char('Employee File Number', size='128'),
    }

hr_employee()
```

**XML file:**

```
<record id="view_hr_employee_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.hr.employee.inherited</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_employee.view_employee_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="name" position="after">
            <field name="emp_file" />
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: thanks, added the code to a new module, copied module to addons directory restarted the computer, updated the module list but the new module is not even visible.

Comment: @user2126867 check the __openerp__.py and __init__.py files. there might be the issue.